# Ubuntu Hard disk is hidden in windows

Tags: hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access Ubuntu Files from Windows on a dual-boot machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95254/how-to-access-ubuntu-files-from-windows-on-a-dual-boot-machine)

I installed ubuntu 12.04 with windows in dual-boot mode in my acer laptop and it took 100GB partition for ubuntu. Now while i'm working with windows, it don't show ubuntu partition. But in ubuntu it shows windows and others partitions also.

I want to know is there a method to show ubuntu partition in windows? Because i want to use free space of ubuntu partition....

Answer (score 1):

At first: yes there is a way. The Problem is that your "Ubuntu partition" is using another filesystem than windows. Its probably ext4, and Windows is not able to handle these filesystems. So even if Windows could show you your Ubuntu partition, you could not use it.

Now you could ask "but why is Ubuntu able to recognize and handle the Windows FAT and NTFS partitions?", well Ubuntu is smarter ;)

For handling some linux partitions on windows, you need some extra software on your system. Maybe you could try this:

- http://www.webupd8.org/2011/08/access-ext4-ext3-or-ext2-partitions-in.html
- http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/

Or you could resize your ubuntu partiton with [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/)

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/ResizingPartition
- http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/

Comment: OK thanks....i got an idea...and i'will try and comment :)