# Defect display driver

Tags: 14.04, drivers, display, restore

I've encountered a quite serious problem with my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
My display driver is defect and I really need this one file on the desktop.
The display will turn black whenever I start Ubuntu.

Is there a way to:
1. Restore to the stock display driver?
2. Reinstall Ubuntu keeping my files?
or 3. Get that one file with Windows 7 (yes, I'm dual booting) or the Ubuntu live CD?

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: You could just use the tty1 to use a terminal to copy the file to a usb stick. You can access tty1 by pressing "ctrl+alt+f1".

Comment: On Windows you could access the files using ext2fsd or similar (see http://askubuntu.com/q/9933/178596, http://askubuntu.com/q/95254/178596), and then you can copy the files over. You can then reinstall Ubuntu from the install disk, as there probably is a reinstall option.

Answer (score 0):

either

-boot in single-user mode (from grub: press *e* then add *single* at the end of the line starting with linux), or

-boot from live-cd and mount your root fs (/)

then rename your /etc/X11/xorg.conf file (`mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.failing` - the path will obviously be different if you mounted your fs from a live-cd)