# Cannot access my windows file

Tags: windows-10

I am using ubuntu 14.04 with windows 10 inbuilt.I cannot access the drives which is in ubuntu though the drives are showing in ubuntu luncher.How can I access these file

Comment: you are not able to access windows drives from ubuntu or ubuntu drives from windows?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by `windows 10 inbuilt`? Are you talking about the `Windows subsystem for Linux (bash)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access Ubuntu Files from Windows on a dual-boot machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95254/how-to-access-ubuntu-files-from-windows-on-a-dual-boot-machine)

Comment: I have had same problem, after doing some poking around I figured each time I shutdown windows and start Ubuntu I am unable to access these drives. If I go into windows and restart it instead of complete shutdown and then start ubuntu, my drives are accessible. I figured it had something to do with Windows protecting drive or something. Try it out see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

*Choose one as per your requirement*

**1. View windows drives in Ubuntu**

Installing Ubuntu in parallel to Windows 8+. It causes problem viewing the windows NTFS drives from ubuntu although it is shown in the Nautilus sidebar.

*To view the windows NTFS drives,*

1. Restart your PC and login to windows
2. Open each partition one time and close the file manager
3. Reboot into Ubuntu.
4. You will be able to access all windows ntfs partitions there

**2. View ubuntu ext partition in Windows**

Windows do not support ext partitions and you won't be able to see the Ubuntu partition in windows.

To view the Ubuntu partition in Windows.

1. Install [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) on windows
2. Open Ext2Fsd
3. You will see the EXT4 partitions in the list
4. Mount the partition and assign partition letter.
5. You will be able to view the EXT4 partition now.

Comment: However, Microsoft says not to change Linux files from within Windows: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/