# How to write to Ext4 Root partition on Window 10?

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, mount, windows, ext4

Long story short, I modified the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme`, which was supposed to change the login screen wallpaper. But I don't know anything about CSS and now I can't boot Ubuntu anymore.

I made my laptop dual boot between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. So I'm expecting to fix that file from Windows. How can I get the root privilege and then access the ubuntu partition on Windows?

These were my attempts:

- Ext2Fsd: It could see the content of all of my partitions, except the root and home. When I mounted them, the root and home partitions just appeared to be empty.
- Ext2Explorer: It displayed no partition (even with run as admin)
- Linux Reader: I mounted the root partition, and could actually go to the directory of the CSS file! But when I try to fix it (by first copy it to Windows, type it back to its original content, and then paste it back to its directory), it says: No such file or directory. I also tried to disable the read-only mount permission but there's always an error from nowhere that stopped the process.
- DiskGenius: Same as Linux Reader: I could get to the CSS file location, copy & paste, but "No such file or directory" again.
- Windows Subsystem for Linux: I went to `/dev`, `ls -l` and looked for sdb1 2 3 4, one of them was my root partition. But there're only a pile of tty files, no sdb. Also went to `/mnt`, which shown me 3 files C D E that were my Windows partitions. I used Ext2Fsd to mount my root as F, and went to `/mnt/F`. It's empty.

I guess those attempts failed because I don't have the permission to write on the root partition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access Ubuntu Files from Windows on a dual-boot machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95254/how-to-access-ubuntu-files-from-windows-on-a-dual-boot-machine)

Comment: @Kulfy I have read the article and tried the softwares it mentioned but with fruitless result.

Comment: There is no good and clean way to write to ext4 partitions from Windows since Windows doesn't simply recognise ext4. To share data you can always use an NTFS partition.

Comment: @Kulfy Well I've read that line too many times but still had hope somehow. Now I think that's a bummer that I'd have to reinstall ubuntu again :(
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Are you getting some errors while booting? If your main purpose is to revert back the changes, you can ask a new question specifying the errors and what caused the error. Files can be edited from a LiveUSB, TTY and even recovery mode. So, re-installing the OS might not be required.

Comment: @Kulfy Oh i didn't think about that. The usb I first used to install Ubuntu was lost. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll go buy a new one tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to Kulfy, I've created a bootable USB burned with Ubuntu. And then, via the terminal, I have successfully copied my file back to its original location by `sudo cp`.

Also, I want to warn any future reader who wants Windows to write to ext4: Don't Do That. After I used DiskGenius on Windows to delete a file on Ext4, the disk I wrote on become corrupted and I had to use `fsck` to fix it.